# How to set local storage in cypress

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, next.js, cypress, end-to-end

I have a simple test

```
describe('Page Test', () => {
  it('button has "contact-next-disabled" class', () => {
    cy.get('.contact-next-disabled')
  })
})
```

But after running the test, cypress shows an error

```
  34 | useEffect(() => {
  35 |   const _contact = getLocalStorage()
> 36 |   if (!_contact.categories.length && !_contact.categoryNameEtc) {
     |                ^
  37 |     PGToaster.showDanger('Please select a category.')
  38 |     router.push('/contact/a-type')
  39 |   }
```

My `getLocalStorage` function is in a separate file from the one I am testing

```
export const getLocalStorage = () => {
  const contact = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('contact'))
  return contact
}
```

Which works together with my `setLocalStorage` function

```
export const setLocalStorage = (contact) => {
  const _contact = getLocalStorage()
  const updateContact = {
    ..._contact,
    ...contact
  }
  window.localStorage.setItem('contact', JSON.stringify(updateContact))
}
```

If I rewrite

```
if (!_contact.categories.length && !_contact.categoryNameEtc)
```

to

```
if (!_contact?.categories.length && !_contact?.categoryNameEtc)
```

The error is gone, but I would like to just set local storage in my cypress test instead of rewriting my code. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs of [`cy.clearLocalStorage()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/clearlocalstorage)

> Cypress automatically runs this command before each test to prevent state from being shared across tests. You shouldn't need to use this command unless you're using it to clear localStorage inside a single test.

You can either set up your tests using [`hooks`](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/writing-and-organizing-tests#Hooks):

```js
before(() => {
  // set localStorage
})
```

or you can use a plugin like [cypress-localstorage-commands](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-localstorage-commands) to preserve localStorage between Cypress tests.